# $scope change not applied in angular 1.2.16

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently upgrading a matured application from angular 1.0.8 to the 1.2.16 release.
Within the application we we do have a lot of directives that encapsulate bootstraps typeahead. Something like this:

```
contacts.directive("contactsearch", 
    function($http, $parse, $modal) {

        return {
            restrict:   'A',
            require:    'ngModel',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                var contacts = Array();
                //... xhr gets called. Then in the bootstrap 
               // update callback when results are present:

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    for (var i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                        var ident = contacts[i].firstName + " " + contacts[i].lastName + " - " + contacts[i].company;
                        if (ident == item) {
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, contacts[i]);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-contactsearch data-ng-model="contact">
```

This used to work just fine. After upgrading to 1.2.16 the contact is still applied to the parent scope attribute specified by data-ng-model, but the view is not being updated. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

Furthermore I'm using the following functions within the directive along with angular parsers and formatters:

```
function toContact(text) {
    if (text == "")
        $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, null);
}

function fromContact(contact) {
    if (contact !== undefined && contact != null) {
        var x = "";
        if (contact.firstName && contact.firstName != null)
            x += contact.firstName;
        if (contact.lastName && contact.lastName != null)
            x += " " + contact.lastName;
        if (contact.company && contact.company != null)
            x += " " + contact.company;

            linkIcon(contact);
            return x;
        }
    }

ngModel.$parsers.push(toContact);
ngModel.$formatters.push(fromContact);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since `contactsearch` doesn't use a isolate scope, is there anything stopping you from directly updating the bound variable directly (i.e. `scope.contact = contacts[i]` rather than using `$apply()` and `$parse()`).

Comment: Since I'm updating the scope outside of any angular event I figured wrap the assignment in an $apply(), otherwise angular would not be aware of the change rightt? The reason for $parse is, that the expression in ng-model could be more complex. Something like foo.bar.contact. At least that is what I've thought would be the correct way to do it. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I conveyed myself incorrectly. Indeed, your use of `$parse` with `$apply` is correct. What I'm wondering is why you you don't instead manipulate the `ng-model` binding using a reference via `scope`. Hopefully this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhp2X/1/) might clarify what I meant to ask.

Comment: Many thanks for the fiddle! Unfortunately I'm still not really getting your point. Directive d1 is not applicable to my problem, since the controllers scope could contain anything. That's wy I'm using ng-model  here. d2 basically contains what I've tried to do. I figured that the contact is set in the scope (using the debugger console). But after the directive is done executing, the assigned value gets lost somehow. That's why the view is not updating. I also use parsers and formatters (see my edit in the original post). Might this be an issue?

Comment: I see where you're coming from now. Unfortunately, without seeing the code, the only other suggestion I have to offer is to check that nothing from the [1.0 to 1.2 Angular migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) would affect you.